# How to close notification when app got killed in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-notifications

We are facing one issue while developing our flutter app.

Scenario : We are using media notification to show/hide notification giving click action on it.

Issue: When we are closing app forcefully(killing or swipe out from recent apps)the notification is still visible. I tried using [WidgetsBindingObserver](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBindingObserver-class.html).

```
 AppLifecycleState _notification;

 @override
 void didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) {
     setState(() { 
         _notification = state;  // detect state inactive/ pause or resume state
     });
 }
```

Using this we can detect **background, active, inactive states** but when killing the app no method get called. We need some thing like `onDestroy` method which is called when you kill any app in native android. How can we handle this scenario in flutter. Please Help.

Comment: seems you need implement this natively and use flutter channel to execute dart code

Comment: I agree with Yauhen Sampir. You must perform this action natively.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Waqar UlHaq but still not clear,can you be more precise . I am handling media notification natively but in flutter life cycle  am not able to get the state where i can handle notification.

Comment: have you found any solution?